# Problems with import BLOB from old database to new in C# SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, binary, blob, database-migration

I have big problem when importing old DB to the new one with different structure.

In the old one I have:

Table: CHART_DATA

CHART_ID - integer, primary key, autoincrement

CHART_DATA - BLOB with binary files

Example hex view of file: 01000000630AC2BF332934BF79E08D43EFF13645

Select from old db:

```
    sql = "SELECT hex(CHART_DATA) FROM CHART_DATA";
            SQLiteCommand select_hex = new SQLiteCommand(sql.ToString(), old_dbConnection);
            reader = select_hex.ExecuteReader();
    int i = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
            {
                chart_hex[i] = reader[0].ToString();
                i++;
            }
```

And when I try save it to the new base i have many problems:

**First try:** Save string to BLOB column:

```
for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlinsert.ToString(), new_dbConnection);
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO chart(chart_file) VALUES (@chart_file)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chart_file", chart_hex[k]]);
        }
```

The result was predictable, string value in column :( (for example: 01000000630AC2BF332934BF79E08D43EFF13645)

**Second try:** Saving as DbType.Binary

```
for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlinsert.ToString(), new_dbConnection);
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO chart(chart_file) VALUES (@chart_file)";
             command.Parameters.Add("@chart_file", DbType.Binary, 20).Value = chart_hex[k];
        }
```

Same result :( (string: 01000000630AC2BF332934BF79E08D43EFF13645)

**Third try:** Conversion of string to byte

```
 for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
            {
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlinsert.ToString(), new_dbConnection);
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO chart(chart_file) VALUES (@chart_file)";
                command.Parameters.Add("@chart_file", DbType.Binary, 20).Value = GetBytes(chart_hex[k]);
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chart_file", GetBytes(chart_hex[k, 1])); //I also try this 

            }

            ...

             static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                return bytes;
            }
```

The result is BLOB object in DB but with problems. File is different from the original:

Original: `01000000630AC2BF332934BF79E08D43EFF13645`

In new DB:

```
31003000300030003000300030003600
33003000410043003200420046003300
33003200390033003400420046003700
39004500300038004400340033004500
4600460031003300360034003500
```

I've run out of ideas how to import this form old DB :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need a string, then don't select a string. Change the destination array to an `object` array and just get the values as they are stored in the old DB. This assumes that the BLOB data is not actually stored in the old DB as text.

```
string sql = "SELECT CHART_DATA FROM CHART_DATA";
SQLiteCommand select_hex = new SQLiteCommand(sql, old_dbConnection);
reader = select_hex.ExecuteReader();
int i = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
  // chart_hex is changed to an object array, not a string array
  chart_hex[i] = reader[0];
  i++;
}
```

Then, simply insert the object values:

```
for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
{
  SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(new_dbConnection);
  command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO chart(chart_file) VALUES (@chart_file)";
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chart_file", chart_hex[k]]);
}
```

The `SQLiteParameter` class should map the object value to a BLOB column affinity in both directions, resulting in the data being retrieved and stored in the same format.